# Unable to calculate product qty

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to calculate the quantity of items in my vue. The problem I'm having is that my computed property isn't picking up my object, because my thinking was as you can see with the commented out section is that I was going to loop through it and calculate the quantity, but since I'm not able to grab `productItems` I'm not able to loop through it.

Here is my code

```
<template>
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Qty</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>

                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr v-for="item in products">
                                            <td>
                                                {{ item['name'] }}
                                            </td>
                                            
                                            <td>
                                                <input style="width: 100px; margin-left: 0; display: inline"
                                                       type="number" class="form-control"
                                                       v-model="productItems[item['name']]['unit']"
                                                >

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td>
                                                Consumption total: {{ consumptionTotal }}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    props: [],
    data(){
        return {
            productItems: {}

    },
    computed:{
        consumptionTotal(){
            console.log(this.productItems);
            // return Object.keys(this.productItems).reduce((carry, item) => {
            //     carry += Number(this.productItems[item]['unit'])
            //     return carry;
            // }, Number(0));
        },
    },
    watch: {

    },
    methods: {

    },
    mounted() {

    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps. Hopefully it will helps you.

Step 1: `productItems` should be an array

Step 2: Calculate functions be like

```
computed: {
consumptionTotal () {
  return this.productItems.reduce((total, item) => {
    total += item.unit
    return total
  }, Number(0))
}
}
```

Step 3: HTML template will be like

```
 <div class="content-header">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-12">
                              <table class="table">
                                  <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                  </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                  <tbody>
                                  <tr v-for="item in productItems" :key="item.id">
                                    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{item.name}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                      <input style="width: 100px; margin-left: 0; display: inline" type="number" class="form-control" :value="item.unit">
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                      Consumption total: {{ consumptionTotal }}
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-jennings-fuw0v)

Comment: I get this.productItems.reduce is not a function

Comment: @GlitterGrace `this.productItems` it should be an `array` which have list of product details. Can you check my demo link. You can see the full code and demo too.